# Reference for universal elliptic curves

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, elliptic-curves, modular-forms

I've seen the following sentence come up in a few papers:

> Consider the modular curve $Y_1(N)$ and let $E$ be the universal elliptic curve over $Y_1(N)$.

This comes up in Deligne's construction of Galois representations for modular forms of weight $k>2$. I'm not sure what "universal elliptic curve" means, and after some googling, I can't seem to find a complete definition / construction of it. So I wanted to ask:

1. Does anyone have a reference which explains the full definition of "universal elliptic curve" (over a modular curve)? Preferably, I'd like a reference which explains the overall philosophy / motivation behind universal elliptic curves, as well as the rigorous definitions.
2. How does one write down an explicit Weierstrass equation for the universal elliptic curve over $Y_1(N)$? For example, if we set say $N=11$, then what is the Weierstrass equation for the universal elliptic curve $E$ over $Y_1(11)$?

Comment: A nice reference is "Modular Forms and Modular Curves" by Diamond and Im, available here: https://people.math.wisc.edu/~boston/Diamond-Im-Modular_forms_and_modular_curves.pdf. The second paragraph of page 32 explains universal elliptic curves very nicely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any $n\geq 1$, one can define a functor $\mathcal{M}_1(n)\colon \mathrm{Schemes}/\mathbb{Z}[\frac1n] \to \mathrm{Groupoids}$, sending a scheme to the groupoid of elliptic curves over it with a chosen point of exact order $n$; the morphisms in the groupoid are the isomorphisms of elliptic curves that respect the chosen point. If $n\geq 4$, the groupoid is equivalent to a set (i.e. there can be no non-trivial automorphism of an elliptic curve that preserves a point of order $n\geq 4$) and the functor is actually represented by a scheme. This scheme might be called $Y_1(n)$. If you define it like this, the universal elliptic curve over $Y_1(n)$ is simply classified by the identity. (For $n<4$, the scheme $Y_1(n)$ is the coarse moduli space of the stack $\mathcal{M}_1(n)$ and the story becomes more complicated.)

But maybe $Y_1(n)$ has another definition for you, e.g. as the quotient of the upper half plane $\mathbb{H}$ by $\Gamma_1(n)$. It is a non-trivial theorem to identify this with the analytification of the $Y_1(n)$ as constructed above. But you can construct the universal elliptic curve in this case also easily in a direct way: Just take the quotient of $\mathbb{H} \times \mathbb{C}$ by the suitable semidirect product of $\Gamma_1(n)$ and $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

Probably, Katz's [$p$-adic properties of modular schemes and modular forms](https://web.math.princeton.edu/%7Enmk/old/padicpropMFMS.pdf) is not the worst place to read about this. From the purely complex point of view you also have Hain's [Lectures on Moduli Spaces of Elliptic Curves](https://arxiv.org/abs/0812.1803).

Regarding explicit Weierstraß equations: in general, this is bound to be difficult as even explicit equations for the $Y_1(n)$ are hard to get. An older article which deals in particular with such equations is *Torsion  groups of elliptic curves with integral j-invariant over quadratic  fields* by  Hans  H. Müller,  Harald  Ströher  and  Horst  G. Zimmer. Regardless of the precise equations for $Y_1(n)$ ones knows however that the universal elliptic curve over it always has a Weierstraß equation of the form
$$y^2 + a_1xy + a_3y = x^3 +a_2x^2,$$
for holomorphic modular forms $a_1, a_2$ and $a_3$ of level $n$ over $\mathbb{Z}[\frac1n]$. This might have been known before, but we give a proof in an article with V. Ozornova: [Rings of modular forms and a splitting for $TMF_0(7)$](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.04425). There we also work out the case $n=7$ in detail.

Comment: Regarding the existence of Weierstraß equations, I asked once a related [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/297111/non-vanishing-modular-forms) about the triviality of the canonical bundle of the universal elliptic curve, maybe you can answer it.

Comment: wonderful! thanks for the description and the references, they were very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

To complete Lennart Meier's nice answer, Baaziz has computed explicit equations for the universal elliptic curve over $Y_1(N)$ up to $N=51$. The method used and the data up to $N=20$ can be found in [Baaziz's article](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0025-5718-10-02332-X).